# React native Animated Value this.props.onScroll is not a function

Tags: react-native, animation, onscroll

how i can understand scrollY is an empty node, and i dont understand why

```
const scrollY= new Animated.Value(0)
const onScroll = Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }], {
    listener: (event: any) => console.log('listerner', event),
    useNativeDriver: false,
  });
```

```
 <ScrollView       
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
              onScroll={onScroll}>
content....
            </ScrollView>
```

scrollY in console.log

```
AnimatedValue {__lastLoopID: {…}, 
__memoizedValue: {…}, 
__children: Array(0),
 __nodeID: 1190, 
__nodeConfig: {…},
 …}__children: (9)
 [AnimatedOperator, AnimatedOperator, AnimatedCallFunc, AnimatedOperator, AnimatedOperator, AnimatedCallFunc, AnimatedOperator, AnimatedOperator, AnimatedCallFunc]__initialized: true__inputNodes: undefined__lastLoopID: {"": -1}__memoizedValue: {"": null}__nodeConfig: {type: "value", value: 0}__nodeID: 1190_animation: null_constant: false_startingValue: 0_value: 0[[Prototype]]: InternalAnimatedValue
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to do but maybe you could try to start from here :

```
 function handleScroll(event){
console.log(event)
}

<ScrollView       
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
              onScroll={(e) => handleScroll(e)}>
content....
            </ScrollView>
```

This how i get the scroll y position.